# How to retrieve the version,artifactId,package of the artifact built on Hudson

Tags: shell, maven, continuous-integration, hudson, artifacts

After building the artifact i am executing a script as a Post Build Action to deploy the artifact. So im trying to read the location where it is built.The environment Variables available in Hudson is not givng me enough information about the artifactId, Version, PackageType of the artifact.

So can anyone help me out on how to get the values for these....

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

All artifacts built by Maven contain META-INF entries that hold this information. Read them as JarFile:

```
JarFile jf = new JarFile(path/to/artifact);
JarEntry propsEntry = jf.getJarEntry("META-INF/maven/pom.properties");
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(jf.getInputStream(propsEntry));
// retrieve the values:
String groupId = props.get("groupId");
String artifactId = props.get("artifactId");
String version = props.get("version");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, My Question is with Hudson how to read this values??i.e, Once you build the artifact it will be archived in some location example is ${BUILD_URL}artifact/hudson_${NODE_NAME}_{JOBNAME}/com/xyz/target/  {ArtifactId}-{version}-{packagetype}. so i need to give the artifactId,version,packagetype to get the artifact. I dont want the user to enter the AVP values instead i want it to be read from HUDSON config file.

Comment: Oh, sorry, thought you were writing a Hudson Plugin. In a shell script, you'll have to do pretty much the same thing, though: unpack the pom.properties file from the JAR / WAR and read it. But I can't really help you much with the details. Try adding `shell` or `bash` to the question's tags

Comment: My Question is with Hudson how to read this values??i.e, Once you build the artifact it will be archived in some location example is ${BUILD_URL}artifact/hudson_${NODE_NAME}_{JOBNAME}/com/xyz/target/ {ArtifactId}-{version}-{packagetype}. so i need to give the artifactId,version,packagetype to get the artifact. I dont want the user to enter the AVP values instead i want it to be read from HUDSON config file.

Answer (score 0):

I might have misunderstood your question completely, but is there a reason not to pick up the artifact via the filesystem and the [WORKSPACE](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-JenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables) environment variable, `${WORKSPACE}/target/...`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Yeah i can use ${WORKSPACE}/target/ instead of ${BUILD_URL}artifact/hudson_${NODE_NAME}_{JOBNAME}/com/xyz/target/

Comment: consider in the POM of my artifact i have mentioned this details 
<groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
<artifactId>sampleapplication</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.1.1</version>

so when i do a Hudson build the war file generated will be {WORKSPACE}/target/sampleapplication-1.1.1-war

My question is unless the user goes to the workspace he will not know the name of the war file generated(i.e,sampleapplication-1.1.1-war)
So is there any way i could get the name of the war file ({artfactId}-{version}-{packaging}) generated??

Answer (score 0):

You can use `http://${BUILD_URL}/job/${JOBNAME}/${BUILDNUMBER}/api/xml?xpath=//artifact/fileName/text()` and set that to an environment variable. This only works if you have 1 artifact, if you have more, then you'll need to do some additional parsing.